# Docker Oracle Database - can't overwrite ENV variables for credentials

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose

I would like to configure an Oracle database on a server. For that, I am using this image from DockerHub:
https://hub.docker.com/r/sath89/oracle-12c/
Having included the image in a `docker-compose.yml` file, I am having trouble with overwriting the default credentials for accessing the database (the username is `system` while the password is `oracle`). This is how my docker-compose.yml file looks like:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
oracle12c-db: 
image: sath89/oracle-12c
restart: always # restart policy
ports:
  - 1521:1521
environment:                     
  - USER=myusername
  - PASS=mypass
  - HOST=oracle-database
  - PORT=1521
  - ORACLE_SID=XE
  - HTTP_PORT=8080
```

After successfully executing the command `docker-compose up`, I am still not able to access the database with the new credentials (only with the default ones). Is my `docker-compose` file syntactically correct or am I missing out something else here? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't you can modify this at run time particularly easily.

Option 1 is to create your own Dockerfile based on [theirs](https://github.com/MaksymBilenko/docker-oracle-12c) and pass in the user and password at build time (or hard code it to something else)

Option 2 is to modify their entrypoint and run the appropriate Oracle commands at startup to change the user/password

Comment: This solves the question then. May I also ask how would I import my own dump file into my database then? The creator of the aforementioned docker image briefly described it, but as a docker newbie I find that hard to understand. Where do I place the .dmp file and do I paste the path of the file into the "docker run" command as an environment variable or?

Comment: Map a volume to a directory on the host server and just put the dmp file in there. If you want the Oracle files to sit outside the container map that too. If you want to reimport the dmp at a later date, delete the .cache file in the backup folder, and all files in the data folder.

E.g. in docker-compose

    `volumes:
      - /datadir:/u01/app/oracle
      - /backupdir:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`